# Woocommerce - Remove cart button depending product (post) status

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, post-status

I created (copied) a custom post status for my old/discontinued product in my function.php and everything is working fine.

Now, I want to make those old product unpurchasable by removing the cart button based and the status product, in this case "expired".

I think i have to use `get_post_status()` and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
```

or by using `$is_purchasable=false`.

But to be frank, i'm a begginer and i don't know how i can create it from scratch...

**Edit :**

I tried two different options but none of them work...

```
function remove_cart_button_expired_product (){
    global $product;
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $post_status = get_post_status($id);


    if ($post_status === 'expired') {
        //echo $id;             // working
        //echo $post_status;    // working

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',1);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',1);
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_cart_button_expired_product');
```

This one doesn't work maybe because of my Divi theme...

```
function product_not_purchasable(){
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $post_status = get_post_status($id);

    if ($post_status === 'expired') {
        //echo $id;             // working
        //echo $post_status;    // working

        $purchasable = false;
        return $purchasable;
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'product_not_purchasable');
```

I saw that this line of code is preferable over the precedent one but it brokes my website when i try to add a product in the cart (no mather the  post status ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find my solution after a few day.

In case someone try to do the same

```
function test_expired_product(){
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $post_status = get_post_status($id);
    $terms= array('cursus-annuel');


    if ($post_status === 'expired' || $post_status === 'canceled') {
        //echo $id;             // working
        //echo $post_status;    // working

        add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'expired_product_message', 20 );
        return;
    }

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat' ) ){
        add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'unpurchasable_product_message', 20 );
        return;
    }
}
add_action('wp','test_expired_product');

function expired_product_message() {
    echo '<p style="color:#e00000;">Ce produit n\'est plus disponible.</p>';
}

function unpurchasable_product_message() {
    echo '<p style="color:#e00000;">Ce produit ne peut pas être acheté en ligne. Veuillez nous contacter afin de reserver ce cours.</p>';
}
```